# Electron: How to add functionality to child window buttons in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

**What we want to achieve**:

- I want to create a button to close child windows, also at the bottom of the window.

[image]

**Problems**:

I have placed text and buttons in a child window created as a WebView. However, I am not sure how to implement the functionality in the button in this child window. In particular, I am not sure how to specifically implement the `closeAllBrowserWindows()`(defined in `src/main/mainProcess.ts` below)  defined in the main process and how to link it to the click event of the button in the child window.

I thought about setting up a handler in the close button of the child window that calls the close function of the main process using [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc), but I am stuck on how exactly to achieve this.

How can I incorporate the functionality into the child window's button in React?
Is it feasible to begin with...?

**Current Implementation:**

`src/main/mainProcess.ts`

```js
import { app, BrowserView, BrowserWindow, dialog } from "electron";
import { ipcChannels } from "@ipc/channel";

export const closeAllBrowserWindows = () => {
  // Processes notification that a window has been closed.
  const allBrowserWindows = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
  allBrowserWindows.forEach((bw) => {
    // Call notification process.
    });
}

export const openAuthBrowser = async (params: Params) => {
  app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 800,
    })

    const filePath = "src/renderer/index.html";
    win.loadFile(filePath).catch((e) => {
      // Execute Error Process.
    });

    const view = new BrowserView()
    win.setBrowserView(view)
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 })
    view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org').catch((e) => {
      // Execute Error Process.
    });

    win.on("close", () => {
      closeAllBrowserWindows();
    });
  })
};
```

`child.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Authentication</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 600px; text-align: center;">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Here is the screen of the authentication tool
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    Close this authentication window.
  </div>
  <div>
    <!---I want to execute closeAllBrowserWindows when this button is pressed.--->
    <button id="closeButton" type="button" onClick="">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```